# d3.js Using Class and Attr to add Color to Text

Tags: javascript, class, d3.js, colors, attributes

I'm new to D3, but studying everything I can.  This is my second post ever to StackOverflow.

The code at the bottom appears in the "Attr()" section of this page:

http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/d3js/dom-manipulation-using-d3js

The problem is that it won't change the text color to red. I've read dozens of articles this afternoon, but nothing works.  I'm aware that I could use an in-line "style" command, but I want to understand all of the alternatives.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .error {
            color: 'red'
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Error: This is dummy error.</p>
    <script>
        d3.select("p").attr("class","error");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's `red`, without quotes, not `"red"`.: `.error { color: red; }`. Have a look: https://jsfiddle.net/5doukbq3/

Comment: Thank you!  I'll contact the TutorialsTeacher.com folks to have them correct the error.  Forgot to mention that I'm also relatively new to CSS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add .classed('classname', true)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .error {
      color: #ff0000;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<p>Error: This is dummy error.</p>
<script>
  // to add
  d3.select("p").classed("error", true);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  The key was your change of color to #ff0000 or @Gerardo's unquoting of 'red'.  Works with either .attr("class", "error") or .classed("error", true).  My reading of several dozen articles today trying to solve this was part of a useful learning curve on my way to greater D3 literacy!